# In apache httpd configuration, what LDAP SASL mechanism is used during ldap authentication?

Tags: apache, ldap, sasl

In apache, SVN repository is configured.

During authentication, ldap (auth basic provider) is used.

In apache httpd configuration, what LDAP SASL mechanism is used during ldap authentication?

Answer (score 1):

SASL authentication isn't available with the Apache ldap module.
For Apache 2.2, mod_authn_sasl allows you to configure that using the saslauthd daemon (not on Windows).